# jQuery UI daterange picker numbers format

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

Is there an option to add a "0" in front of the numbers with one character?

ie: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

become: 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/EHNab/

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
            if (dayOfMonth >= 1 && dayOfMonth <= 9) {
                return [true, 'ui-change-format', ''];
            }
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.ui-change-format a::before { 
  content: "0";
}
```

Comment: This on is nice :) + 1

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no predefined option in `UI Datepicker`. You should write your custom code for this:

I write some sample code on `beforeShow` and `onChangeMonthYear` events, try this:

```
$('#picker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (txt, inst) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("#ui-datepicker-div").find('table tr td[data-handler="selectDay"] > a').each(function(){
             if($(this).text().trim().length < 2){
               $(this).text("0" + $(this).text())
             }
         });            
      }, 100);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("#ui-datepicker-div").find('table tr td[data-handler="selectDay"] > a').each(function(){
             if($(this).text().trim().length < 2){
                $(this).text("0" + $(this).text())
             }
         });            
      }, 100);
    }
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vLEhb/26/)

Answer (score -1):

Some work around may help, see below.

```
function addZero() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.ui-state-default').each(function () {
            var t = $(this).text();
            if (t.length == 1) {
                $(this).text('0' + t);
            }
        });
    }, 10);
}
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: addZero,
    beforeShow: addZero
});
```